# When you bring a wagon into camp, where does it go?

Tags: red-dead-redemption-2

Earlier I brought a four-horse wagon into camp at Horseshoe Overlook. It made me dismount the wagon and explained that I can't bring wagons into camp but it would be available again when I left. Now I can't find it anywhere. What happened to it?

Comment: It's hard to say where it went exactly. Normally, **owned** horses will go to a hitching post located near the entryway of the camp (where the Horse Station will be once you unlock it). This _should_ also be the case for horses (or wagons) that you do not own. However, I can imagine something might have happened to scare them off, or cause them to wander off.

Comment: I've had that happen to me, a cut scene began and I spawned in the camp and not in the wagon. I found the wagon just on the outside of the 1st camp when following the trail out.